# SOAP API call with PHP

Tags: php, soap

I have been working on this for a week now and have trouble executing this code. I want to retrieve data via SOAP and work with it in PHP. My trouble is, that I am having trouble sending the `RequesterCredentials`.

I will show the XML code so you all can see the information I am trying to send, and then the PHP code I am using.

#### XML sample code

```
POST /AuctionService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: apiv2.gunbroker.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 200
SOAPAction: "GunBrokerAPI_V2/GetItem"

<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <soap:Header>
       <RequesterCredentials xmlns="GunBrokerAPI_V2">
         <DevKey>devkey</DevKey>
         <AppKey>appkey</AppKey>
       </RequesterCredentials>
     </soap:Header>
     <soap:Body>
    <GetItem xmlns="GunBrokerAPI_V2">
      <GetItemRequest>
        <ItemID>312007942</ItemID>
        <ItemDetail>Std</ItemDetail>
      </GetItemRequest>
    </GetItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

### PHP code that I am using to make the call

```php
$client = new SoapClient("http://apiv2.gunbroker.com/AuctionService.asmx?WSDL");

$appkey = 'XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX';
$devkey = 'XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX';

$header = new SoapHeader('GunBrokerAPI_V2', 'RequesterCredentials', array('DevKey' => $devkey, 'AppKey' => $appkey), 0);
$client->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));

$result = $client->GetItem('312343077');

echo '<pre>', print_r($result, true), '</pre>';
```

#### The result I get

```
stdClass Object
(
    [GetItemResult] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Timestamp] => 2012-11-07T18:17:31.9032903-05:00
        [Ack] => Failure
        [Errors] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ShortMessage] => GunBrokerAPI_V2 Error Message : [GetItem]
                // You must fill in the 'RequesterCredentialsValue'
                // SOAP header for this Web Service method.
                [ErrorCode] => 1
            )
// The rest if just an array of empty fields that
// I could retrieve if I wasn’t having problems.
```

I’m not sure if the problem is the way I’m sending the SoapHeaders or if I am misunderstanding the syntax. How can I fix it?

Comment: You are sending `RequesterCredentials` while ws is requesting `RequesterCredentialsValue`

Comment: Just wanted to comment the exact same thing. Read the error message, it contains some info `RequesterCredentialsValue` is missing and from your code: not set. So the error message looks good in my eyes.

Comment: changing to RequesterCredentialsValue unfortunately gives the same result. It just seems that its not being sent with the call

Comment: perhaps the URL i am using in the first paramter of SoapHeader doesnt make sense?

Comment: Stop guessing, just take a look: Enable the trace option and use the __getLast*() methods.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="GunBrokerAPI_V2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns2="http://apiv2.gunbroker.com/AuctionService.asmx?WSDL">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns2:RequesterCredentialsValue>
      <xsd:string>a894a5cc-fcb3-4dec-92bc-fa397efbabf3</xsd:string>
      <xsd:string>cecadfef-7e41-4c06-b223-94f6ba493411</xsd:string>
    </ns2:RequesterCredentialsValue>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:GetItem/>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an object instead of an associative array for headers:

```
$obj = new stdClass();

$obj->AppKey = $appkey;
$obj->DevKey = $devkey;

$header = new SoapHeader('GunBrokerAPI_V2', 'RequesterCredentials', $obj, 0);
```

And the next problem you might face will be at the `GetItem` call. You also need an object, wrapped in an associative array:

```
$item = new stdClass;
$item->ItemID = '312343077';
$item->ItemDetail = 'Std';

$result = $client->GetItem(array('GetItemRequest' => $item));
```

Comment: Very nicely done. I dropped this code in and it worked like a charm. Thanks so much!